# HttpRemotingHandlerFactory System.MissingFieldException

Tags: c#, .net, iis, remoting

I have an application hosted in iis. Very occasionally (every month or two) the following exception is thrown:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for "System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Http.HttpRemotingHandlerFactory" threw an exception. ---> System.MissingFieldException: Field not found: ?.s_webServicesFactoryType.

The application is set to automatically recycle every day and it seems sometimes after a recycle this exception is thrown repeatedly until the next recycle.

The only hit I can find on google is http://mcfunley.com/135/bizarro-typeinitializationexception-in-systemruntimeremoting, which describes the exact same problem but there doesn't seem to be a solution posted.

Has anyone experienced this before?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm experiencing a very similar issue.  I seem to encounter with a struct that is a property of a control that gets loading dynamically (LoadControl).  If I change a field to a property in the struct, I ge the error.